# String to date error (Conversion from string to type date is not valid)

Tags: vb.net, date, ms-access, type-conversion

I want to crate date as MS Access like date (example -> #mm/dd/yyy#) input date can be string or date so I have created object variable to hold value of date. Then I convert it to msaccess date.
but it gives error. See the picture attached.

[image]

Before posting this question I had searched a lot, but I don't understand the solutions I found.
A major solution is `ParseExact("Date String", "Format", System. IFormatProvider)`. But in my editor Intellisense does not recognize culturevalue. It tells me culturevalue is not defined.

Then I tried `Date.tryparse()`. It worked, but if I have to use this, then what is use of CDate conversion function?

Edit 1 :
Date.tryparse() does not work it returns false

in vb6
"#" & Month(dateIn) & "/" & Day(dateIn) & "/" & Year(dateIn) & "#"
works perfectly

Comment: You should provide code and error message as formatted text, not image. You have tag vba but narrative says vb6 and `Date.tryparse()` code is not VBA. Correct tags.

Comment: I don't see any code that converts to date type. Syntax of Format() function looks wrong and Format would result in a string, not a date value. If it isn't already a valid date structure, I don't see how the Month, Day, Year functions could work and wouldn't be necessary if it is a valid structure.

Comment: Why say Date.tryparse() worked then say it doesn't? Edit question to leave only the correct statement.

Comment: You're using vb.net not VBA...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @June7 date.tryparse() worked means it does not generate fatal error. date.tryparse() does not works means it always return false. it don't seem useful to me.

Comment: to all, I am new to vb.net programming. I had worked in vb6, long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you ask for a *string expression* for a VBA date value.

That can be done like this:

```vb
Dim DateIn As DateTime

DateIn = DateTime.Today

Dim Rval As String

Rval = DateIn.ToString("'#'MM'/'dd'/'yyyy'#'")

Console.WriteLine(Rval)

' Output:
' #07/10/2022#
```

Comment: I already changed my function that return string. but i wanted it to return date. with mm/dd/yyyy format. lets hope it will not create problem in storing to and retrieving from database. and even in comparing datevalue in sql query in future.